# Best way to create dynamic list of links/buttons in iOS5 view controller

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to create a dynamic set of links/buttons in an iOS5 view controller and am trying to figure out what might be the best way to do this.

For eg:

Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
:
:
Item N

Each of the Items is a link/button that is clickable and will do some action, like load another screen etc based on the link.

I don't know ahead of time how many items there might be so if all the items don't fit on the screen, I need to be able to scroll to view.

My question:
1. What is a better way of doing this? I could just create the labels and buttons dynamically but this seems rather cumbersome and I'm not entirely sure how I would differentiate between the different buttons (essentially I'd need some index to find out which Item was clicked).
2. Alternatively, I was wondering if I can just render this page as HTML and just have links? I've never done this and not sure how I'd associate a button with a link.

Any suggestions?

AK

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to use the `tag` property to store the index value you need when you create the button. Then evaluate it in the button tap handler by accessing using `button.tag`.
2. Maybe you can try [Cordova](http://incubator.apache.org/cordova/) for an HTML based approach. I'm not too familiar with it though, so I can't say for sure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess the tag property is the only way I would know how to do that. Let me look at Cordova and see if its suitable. Thanks

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough when I mentioned the HTML approach. What I really meant was if I should just render that particular screen as HTML. I still want to use Xcode and the iOS framework for everything else.

Comment: I see. Then I suggest to just go implement them as buttons (or any other tappable element) with the index in the tag to know how you should handle the action.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can assign UIButton `tag` property based on the button index. If any events were to trigger, you could recognize which button the event belongs to by checking the `tag`.

Sample :

```
// Initializing some buttons
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button1.tag = 1;
[button1 addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(buttonPushed:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button2.tag = 2;
[button2 addTarget:self 
            action:@selector(buttonPushed:) 
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Selector for button events :

```
- (void)buttonPushed:(id)sender {
    ...
    if ([sender tag] == 1) {
        // do something after button1 event
    } else if () {
        // do something after button2 event
    }
    ...
}
```

(2) If you choose to do it in HTML, you could check out [CMHTMLView](https://github.com/mureev/CMHTMLView)

Comment: Thanks. As for the HTML, I really meant if it made sense to just do that one screen in HTML, not the entire app. This is just one screen where I want to display information as a series of links.

Comment: if you check out CMHTMLView, it is only a view, which you can use  inside a ViewController. The good thing is CMHTMLView provides an easy way for you to communicate between ViewController and the HTMLView on any click event via block programming.